# Function to Create Start/Stop Time Variables for Time-Dependent Survival Analysis

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I'm preparing a longitudinal dataset for time-dependent Cox regression in R. I am following patients from the date of hospital discharge (`HospDis`) through either censorship or death (`Death`) for up to 10 years post-hospitalization. I have data for the follow-up year (`FUPeriod`), follow-up date (`FU`), and a time-varying variable (`Score`), as shown in the table below:

| ID | FUPeriod | HospDis | FU | Death | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2011-01-01 | NA | NA | 75 |
| 1 | 1 | 2011-01-01 | 2011-10-10 | NA | 34 |
| 1 | 2 | 2011-01-01 | NA | 2012-03-15 | NA |
| 2 | 0 | 2011-02-18 | NA | NA | 115 |
| 2 | 1 | 2011-02-18 | 2012-01-07 | NA | 124 |
| 2 | 2 | 2011-02-18 | 2013-01-09 | NA | 122 |
| 2 | 5 | 2011-02-18 | 2016-07-07 | NA | 126 |
| 2 | 10 | 2011-02-18 | 2021-04-30 | NA | 125 |

I'd like to create a function that creates the start/stop time interval variables (in months since hospital discharge) [needed to use the {survival} package in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) based on the `HospDis`, `FU`, and `Death` data, as well as a censoring variable based on `Death`. The function should produce the following:

| ID | FUPeriod | HospDis | FU | Death | Score | Start | Stop | Event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2011-01-01 | NA | NA | 75 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2011-01-01 | 2011-10-10 | NA | 34 | 0 | 9.263518 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 2011-01-01 | NA | 2012-03-15 | NA | 9.263518 | 14.42163 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 2011-02-18 | NA | NA | 115 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2011-02-18 | 2012-01-07 | NA | 124 | 0 | 10.61191 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 2011-02-18 | 2013-01-09 | NA | 122 | 10.61191 | 22.70226 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 | 2011-02-18 | 2016-07-07 | NA | 126 | 22.70226 | 64.59001 | 0 |
| 2 | 10 | 2011-02-18 | 2021-04-30 | NA | 125 | 64.59001 | 122.3477 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(end = interval(HospDis, FU) %/% months(1),
         start = lag(end),
         event = if_else(is.na(Score), 1, 0)) %>%
  relocate(start, .after = Score)

# A tibble: 8 × 9
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID FUPeriod HospDis    FU         Death      Score start   end event
  <dbl>    <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1        0 2011-01-01 NA         NA            75    NA    NA     0
2     1        1 2011-01-01 2011-10-10 NA            34    NA     9     0
3     1        2 2011-01-01 NA         2012-03-15    NA     9    NA     1
4     2        0 2011-02-18 NA         NA           115    NA    NA     0
5     2        1 2011-02-18 2012-01-07 NA           124    NA    10     0
6     2        2 2011-02-18 2013-01-09 NA           122    10    22     0
7     2        5 2011-02-18 2016-07-07 NA           126    22    64     0
8     2       10 2011-02-18 2021-04-30 NA           125    64   122     0
```

Comment: Great answer! But for posterity and for others with the same problem, try to [move away from posting code-only responses](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and explain a little about what your answer does.

Comment: @Tom This accomplishes most of what I need, but it doesn't add 0's to the `start` and `end` variables for the baseline data (i.e., when `FUPeriod` = 0 and `HospDis` is the only available date). It also produces whole numbers for the `start` and `end` variables rather than the continuous number of months from `HospDis` to either `FU` or `Death`. Also, `event` seems to be based on the availability of the `Score` data rather than on whether or not the person has a non-missing `Death` date, but I think I can take care of that by changing to ```if_else(is.na(Death), 0, 1))```

Comment: @Tom Also (I think because the `end` variable doesn't reference `Death` at all), there is no `end` value for the third row, which should have a value of 14.42163 (or 14, if using the "%/%" operator).